# SQL/HTML - Statements wont load on the HTML page

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, web, localhost

Me and a friend of mine are working on a school project. We only have a little problem with implementing the SQL into HTML. And as our informatics teacher is of no help, I hope you are.
Our problem is the following.

We have coded our SQL part into the HTML, also guided by online tutorials...

Now our teacher sorted it to this:

```
    <?php

mysql_connect("Localhost", "root", "usbw") or die (mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('aanbod');

$query = "SELECT merk, model FROM Aanbod";
$result = mysql_query($query);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["merk"] . "</td>
<td>" . $row["model"] . "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysql_close();


?>
```

And still getting this error, now on the webpage:

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\USBWebserver v8.67\root\merkmodelshow.php on line 141

Supposing the problem is in this line:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

If anyone could help us with this project. It's due soon :C

Regards,

Demiën en Bo.

Comment: As a first step close the string `"Localhost` in your first line by adding a `"`.

Comment: Yes, I did that now, and edited the post. Our teacher finally helped a bit. Though he was unable to solve it. [No idea how he got the job]

Comment: For your new version of your code and its error see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole. Your query failed and `$result` is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use missed closing ;

try

```
    <?php

mysql_connect("Localhost", "root", "usbw") or die (mysql_error ());


    mysql_select_db('aanbod');


    $query = "SELECT 'a'=COUNT(nr) FROM Aanbod";


    $result = mysql_query($query);


    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['a'] . "</td></tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";


    mysql_close();
   ?>
```

But now the site displays this error:

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\USBWebserver v8.67\root\merkmodelshow.php on line 141

This suggests the problem is in this line:"

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

Though we weren't able to resolve the problem [yet]

change your query to 
  $query ="  SELECT *, ( select COUNT(nr) FROM Aanbod) as a from Aanbod";

Comment: Our dear-ish teachet sorted it to this:

Please read added content to mainpost

Comment: change your mysql query  $query = "SELECT 'a'=COUNT(nr) FROM Aanbod"; to   $query = "SELECT name, count(*) as a FROM Aanbod";

Comment: $query = "SELECT COUNT(nr) as a FROM Aanbod";

Comment: My DB http://i.imgur.com/gi9azt6.png there are some more rows further down, but I think it is clear
Tried that, unforunately the page goes blanc then.

Comment: try replasing this query  $query = "SELECT * ,(select COUNT(nr)  FROM Aanbod)as a FROM Aanbod";

Comment: Again the error which indicates this line is false: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

Comment: @DemiënDrost The names of your columns and your database are probably case-sensitive. Instead of `Aanbod` you should use `aanbod` as you did in the screenshot you submitted. The columns you are trying to SELECT in your version are called `Merk` and `Model` in your database.

Comment: change table name Aanbod to  aanbod